# What is this character mean and how to decode these type of characters?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, xml-parsing

I am getting an xml with few special characters like these **Pre‿charged** ‿ and when Iam parsing this data, Iam unable to parse. In my xml Iam getting **PrexE2x80?Charged** or **Preâ€?charged** it there any way to encode this ?
Sample code :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        Document document = null;

        try 
        {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(xmlFile); // xml data in string format
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
        {
            System.out.printf("Failed to parse XML Feed data", e);
        }
```

I tried UTF-8, ANSII and few other encoding techniques.
Edit :
Reading xml data like below

```
StringBuffer outputData = new StringBuffer();
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;

        try 
        {
            url = new URL(data_url);
            is = url.openStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                outputData.append(line.trim());
            }
            br.close();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException mue) 
        {
            LOGGER.error("MalformedURLException while fetching feed data", mue);
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            LOGGER.error("IOException while fetching feed data", ioe);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (is != null) 
                {
                    is.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe) 
            {
                // Silent fail
            }
        }

        return outputData.toString();
```

When we hit the URL in browser,it look like - [image: Browser visibility].
After reading data into file, it look like [image: After reading]

After reading data directly from URL to file, instead of converting it into String, Iam getting data like this [image: Direct data]

After using Files.copy(URI.create(data_url).toURL().openStream(), Path.of("data-copy.x")) function, my output look like
[image: testing]

Comment: How is the XML data getting into a String? The deciding error is probably being introduced at that point.

Comment: @TimMoore, reposted question again on how I am getting data into string ? Do I need to read data in any other way ?

Comment: You should post your xml code (formatted) containing those UNDERTIE (Unicode name) characters

Comment: (And that would be a relevant extract from `data_url`)

Comment: I would recommend passing the `InputStream` directly to `builder.parse` rather than reading into a `String` first. That way, it will use the encoding declared in the XML declaration inside the data. I suspect it isn't UTF-8.

Comment: @TimMoore, If I pass InputStream directly, the output is Pre?charged, it is same like UTF-8, question mark remains same. the expected output is Pre-Charged.(when I hit my URL in browser, Iam able to see Pre-Charged )

Comment: Is it possible for us to hit the URL? btw *Pre-Charged* (what you just wrote) and *Pre‿Charged* (what you wrote originally) are totally different

Comment: @g00se, sorry Its secured, I can explain you. when I hit the URL in Google chrome, Iam able to see Pre-Charged. But when I am trying to read it using above code, Iam getting PrexE2x80?Charged in my file. I copied that(PrexE2x80?Charged) and pasted in search bar or some text file Iam able to see Pre‿Charged

Comment: Finally, I want to read the data how  it look like in browser (simply I need Pre-Charged in my file also)

Comment: `E2 80 BF` is the UTF-8 encoding of the 'undertie' character. Exactly how are you looking at the *file* and can you please paste a *small screenshot* of it in the question

Comment: @g00se, added screenshot (how it is looking in my file)

Comment: You didn't say *how* you're looking at that. Whatever it is, it's probably reading it as 7/8 bit encoding instead of UTF-8

Comment: @g00se, added before and after screenshots. If I read the data in UTF-8 format, Iam getting Pre?Charged (it is converting into a question mark instead of -)

Comment: I would recommend trying to simplify the code to isolate the stage of processing where the error is introduced. What happens if you don’t parse the file but only read it from the URL and write it directly to a file? Do you still see incorrect characters? If so, you know that the parsing and DOM processing isn’t the problem. If not, you know that it is.

Comment: What g00se is trying to explain is that it could well be that the data in the file is 100% correct, but the application you’re using to view the file is reading it incorrectly. See if you can prove or disprove this. Be a scientist: make a hypothesis and try to falsify it, then repeat until you have a hypothesis that your tests support.

Comment: *When we hit the URL in browser,it look like ... After reading data into file, it look like* You *still* have not told us *how* you look at it

Comment: @g00se, I need to read the data as Pre-Charged, but Iam getting PrexE2x80?Charged.

Comment: You are continuing to *not answer* the question

Comment: As per your suggestion, after reading the data directly to file , there is some progress (uploading progress screenshot to question). When I encode that file to ANSI by using  Notepad++ options, Iam getting desired output, but unable to do that in code level using java

Comment: @g00se, sorry for that, I am able to look as Pre-Charged, Iam able to see the data in chrome browser as Pre-Charged, but in notepad++ it is having special characters

Comment: Maybe you don't have notepad++ set to UTF-8?

Comment: Or maybe the font used in Notepad++ doesn’t have that character. Try setting it to use the same font that Chrome is using, if it isn’t already.

Comment: By default my Notepad++ is having UTF-8 only, if I try to use "Covert to ANSI" option in NotePad++, it is working as expected. But now, my problem here is, from code level how to parse that file having "square box" in between them, ultimate goal is to get the data as "Pre-Charged". I have to parse my XML.

Comment: Previously, Iam unable to convert that data in Notepad++ also, but now as per your suggestions Iam able to convert that in NotePad++. Lastly I have to parse that XML. Trying all possible ways to convert that "Square Box" to "-"

Comment: If I copy my data from NotePad++ and paste it anywhere like Browser or some text editor, it is working perfectly fine (getting Pre-Charged) . Seems I have to read it correctly now.

Comment: Can you use a hex editor to confirm what bytes are actually in the file at that point? I’m not personally familiar with Notepad++ but the important thing is to work backwards from how things look to what bytes are in the data, and if the byte data are changing at some point in the processing, isolate which code causes that change. Then, if you don’t understand why that code causes the change, that’s the right time to create a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: *Trying all possible ways to convert that "Square Box" to "-"* This is confusing. Can you explain why you posted something quite different (**‿** - in bold - the 'undertie' character) at the beginning of the question?

Comment: @g00se, Goal is to convert untertie to hypen (‿ to - ), when I write data directly to file using streams, Iam geting square box (as shown in screenshot) in my file. Chrome and some editors are converting undertie character to hypen. but I need to convert that at code level without any editors.

Comment: OK, glad we got that cleared. Try the following. If it suits, I'll post it as the answer: in place of *outputData.append(line.trim());* do `outputData.append(line.trim().replaceAll("\u203F", "-"));` Actually, that undertie looks like an input error in that context anyway

Comment: @g00se, Its not working, because in line.trim() method, we are not getting "\u203F" to replace it.

Comment: @TimMoore, I tried the way you suggested, before I send byte array to file, I tried to read the byte values from byte[], Iam getting -30, -128, -112 as byte values, is there any possible way to decode those negative byte values ?

Comment: Are you able to post a link to a direct copy of the data? If so, i'll give you the code to use

Comment: I cannot send you link, but I can send you those xmls, is there any way to send the files ?

Comment: I need to see a literal copy of the url made with `Files.copy(URI.create(data_url).toURL().openStream(), Path.of("data-copy.x"));`

Comment: I have that file ready, but unable to upload it in stackoverflow, is there any way to send the file ?

Comment: @g00se, Edited question attached screenshot, after using your method, how the data look like.

Comment: No it's no good posting a picture of it. Maybe upload to Google Drive and post a public link

Comment: @g00se, here is the link for the file, you can download it and open in Notepad++ or parse it : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t237RD_hc2Bly4Ipw6npQ-yqhQc9AL2t/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Different character. That's a Unicode HYPHEN. Try instead `outputData.append(line.trim().replaceAll("\u2010", "-"));`

Comment: We know that decoded string is pre-charged If you see it is using browser and If you see it using Notepad++ it is Pre (SquareBox) charged so If you read the file using java and print it in eclipse that might be different pre (something) charged and If you use different tool that would be different .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the code you are using rather the issue is with the client you were using to view the file which is Notepad++ (Open the same file in notepad you will see pre-charged like you have seen when you open google drive link).

I have downloaded the file and checked the encoding it is utf-8 and you were using same technique to read as well.

If you are seeing the pre?charged in any other client
For Example If you print the **output Data** in the eclipse console you will see **pre?charged** it might be because of the below settings

Right-Click on project -> properties -> Resource -> check Text file Encoding
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5QYy.png)
It might be other than UTF-8
If it is not UTF-8 click on **other** dropdown and select UTF-8
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcQyX.png)

Now rerun the method You will See **pre-charged**

The display of data will be different with the different clients Its always good to  check what kind of decoding used by the client. It should be the same as the one which is used to encode the data.

```
String s = "‐";
ByteBuffer buffer =StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(s);
System.out.println("XmlFileReader.main() "+newString(buffer.array(),StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
System.out.println("XmlFileReader.main() "+newString(buffer.array(),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
System.out.println("XmlFileReader.main() "+newString(buffer.array(),StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
System.out.println("XmlFileReader.main() "+newString(buffer.array(),StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
System.out.println("XmlFileReader.main() "+newString(buffer.array(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

OUTPUT:

```
XmlFileReader.main() 胢�
XmlFileReader.main() â€
XmlFileReader.main() ���
XmlFileReader.main() �
XmlFileReader.main() ‐
```

Even in the notepad++ If you change the encoding you will see the expected data
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGrJ8.png)

Comment: Personally, I would still run the code I gave you - nothing is really gained by using a Unicode hyphen over an 'ascii one'. It's just a potential problem source, as you've demonstrated